# Mysql search multipule value from comma seperated string

Tags: mysql

Here I want to search like

I have a string say $var = "1,3,5,7" 
And
in my table say table student there is a column say column_abc

And this column contain values like

column_abc 
2,3,45,6
1,3,4,5,8
3,4,6,9
1,5,10,13,34

I want to search $var against that column column_abc

can anybody help me

In result I want rows which contain any number present in $var

Comment: What do you want in your result ? Rows containing any of those numbers in $var ? or all of the numbers in var ?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you want to search in the table students for the value of column_abc? In that case you can use the following PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `column_abc` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . "'");
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may work for you ...

```
 where column_abc regexp '(^|,)$var($|,)'
```

If $var is equal to 2, then it will find it twice in the below scenario:

```
 2,3,45,6,12
 1,2,3,4,5,8
 3,4,6,9
 1,5,10,13,34
```

EDIT:  Just re-read your question, and you were looking for an entire string of numbers, and not just one ....

Comment: I think he need $var as like  2,4 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

declare @search int(10)
declare @Search2 int(10)
Set @Search = '1,2,3,4'
Set @Search2 = @Search+'%'
select * from student where _abc like @Search2

Comment: I do not understand what you write what @ mean here?